# Python replacing one list with another

Tags: python, list, replace

I have one list like this `list = []` and in this list there are elements like this
15,a,90 -
16,c,60 -
17,e,50 -

The output of the list[0] is 15,16,17 and i have code like this

```
ogrno = input("a")
    for i in ogr.list:
        if ogrno == i[0]:
        add = [input("new number "),input("new word"),input("new number")
        i = add
```

I want to add a new list instead of the selected line here.But "i" not used.

Comment: It's easy to get confused as to what a variable is, and what assigning to a variable does. It seems like that has happened here. Variables are "name tags" on values. So `foo = 42` is like saying "I'm going to call you (42) 'foo' for now". The thing to note that often gets confusing, is that when you assign something to a variable, the something doesn't go "inside" the variable, but rather the variable gets attached to that something. In fact, it's more correct to say "assign a variable to something" than the other way around, even though that is less commonly said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fails for the same reason that `a = 3; i = a; i = 2` doesn't change the value of `a`: assigning to a name *never* affects the object currently bound to that name. If you want to change what a list references, you need to assign to the list slot itself.

```
for i, value in enumerate(ogr.list):
    if ogrno == value[0]:
        ogr.list[i] = [input("new number "),input("new word"),input("new number")]
```

Comment: i have another error.When entering the last element in the list the error output is like this IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: If `value[0]` raises an `IndexError`, then `value` is empty. You need to check for that before trying to index the list.